# jade nodejs Multiple buttons with modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug, semantic-ui

Hi i have multiple buttons in for loop, i want to show only one modal when i click the button, but now, it shows all modals(multiple modals for every button) when i click the button. how do i fix the problem?

```
      each user in users
        tr
          td= user.email
          td
            .ui.basic.blue.button#more More
              .ui.mini.modal.myModal
                i.close.icon
                .header
                  | #{user.email}
                .content
                  |#{user.email}  
                .actions
                  .ui.positive.right.labeled.icon.button
                     | Yep!
                     i.checkmark.icon
```

Jquery

```
   $('#more').click(function(){
      $('.ui.modal.myModal').modal({
      }).modal('show');
    });
```

Comment: `$('.ui.modal.myModal')` is selecting all of the modals created in your `each` loop.

Comment: In the `each` loop, you are creating many buttons with `#more`, why (ids should be unique)?

Answer (score 0):

It's showing every modal because you have as many #more buttons as you have users.  The id "more" should be used on one and only one element if you follow JavaScript/HTML best practices, but as you are seeing that's not a rule that's strictly enforced.  When you use `$('#more')` as your selector it is returning every button with that id.

To fix this, I'd recommend that you use one modal and pass the relevant details into it with the onclick function.  This will pass the user's e-mail (or id or whatever) into the function.  Note that the modal is outside the table altogether.  Note that I've changed the `#more` id into a class `.more` as classes the proper way to group multiple elements.

```
table
  each user in users
    tr
      td= user.email
      td
        .ui.basic.blue.button.more(onclick='showMore(' + user.email + ')') More


.ui.mini.modal.myModal#theModal
  i.close.icon
  .header
    span#modalHeader
  .content
    span#modalContent
  .actions
    .ui.positive.right.labeled.icon.button Yep!
      i.checkmark.icon
```

Then your script will pass the content into the modal and show it:

```
function showMore(email){

  $('#modalHeader').html(email);
  $('#modalContent').html(email);
  $('.ui.modal.myModal').modal('show');

}
```

If you wanted to get really tricky you could pass the entire object into the function call and then the showMore function could use any property:

```
.ui.basic.blue.button#more(onclick='showMore(' + JSON.stringify(user) + ')') More
```

The function would then look like this:

```
function showMore(user){

  $('#modalHeader').html(user.name);
  $('#modalContent').html(user.email);
  $('.ui.modal.myModal').modal('show');

}
```